# Is there a software to solve functional inequalities?

Tags: inequalities, mathematical-software

Suppose I have some inequalities that my function (say $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$) needs to satisfy, like $\forall x,y\; f(x)+f(y)\le f(x+y)$ and $f(1)=0$. Is there some software that can find solutions/prove that there's no such function?

Of course, the problem is undecidable in general, but this doesn't rule out some software that could be efficient in practice.

Comment: It would be great to have such software. I would be greatly and very pleasantly surprised, though, if it existed. Indeed, even if we only consider algebraic functional equations, where the values of $f$ at different points are related by an algebraic inequality, this would be an infinite-dimensional problem of real algebraic geometry, whereas existing algorithms struggle with such problems even in rather low dimensions. By the way, the example problem you mention is a problem of infinite-dimensional linear programming.

Comment: Oh, so that's what this is called! I'll try to read about it.